# Getters and setters or return methods?

Tags: java

Messing about with a guess the number game here, 2 ways I can do it. I can create an object class called Number, then use getters and setters such as `number.setPlayerNumber` and then use `number.getPlayerNumber` in my if statements to determine the winner.

This means I would not need to use static variables and they would remain in scope of the method only(Making it less cumbersome later?(but can make the main method look messy?...))

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NumberGuess {

    static Number number = new Number();

    static boolean win;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int cpuNumber = generateNumber();
        int playerNumber = playerNumber();
        printResults();
        winCondition();

    }

    public static int generateNumber() {
        System.out.println("Generating a number");
        System.out.println("Done!");

        Random rand = new Random();
        int cpuNumber = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        number.setCpuNumber(cpuNumber);     

        return cpuNumber;
    }

    public static int playerNumber() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String playerNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a number between 1 and 10",
                "Player Turn", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        number.setPlayerNumber(Integer.parseInt(playerNum));

        return Integer.parseInt(playerNum);
    }

    public static void printResults(){
        System.out.println("The computers number was: " + number.getCpuNumber());
        System.out.println("Your number was: " +  number.getPlayerNumber());

    }

    public static void winCondition(){

        if(number.getCpuNumber() != number.getPlayerNumber()){
            if(number.getPlayerNumber() < number.getCpuNumber()){
                System.out.println("You lose!\n"
                        + "Guess too low!");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("You lose!\n"
                            + "Guess too high!");
                }
        }

        if(number.getPlayerNumber() == number.getCpuNumber()){
            System.out.println("You have guessed correct. You win!");
        }
    }

}
```

I could also just go ahead and use return methods. Meaning i would need to make every variable static in order to use them in methods that use them for decisions.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NumberGuess {

    static Number number = new Number();

    static int cpuNumber = generateNumber();
    static int playerNumber = playerNumber();
    static boolean win;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        printResults();
        winCondition();

    }

    public static int generateNumber() {
        System.out.println("Generating a number");
        System.out.println("Done!");

        Random rand = new Random();
        int cpuNumber = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;   

        return cpuNumber;
    }

    public static int playerNumber() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String playerNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a number between 1 and 10",
                "Player Turn", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        return Integer.parseInt(playerNum);
    }

    public static void printResults(){
        System.out.println("The computers number was: " + number.getCpuNumber());
        System.out.println("Your number was: " +  number.getPlayerNumber());

    }

    public static void winCondition(){

        if(cpuNumber != playerNumber()){
            if(playerNumber() < cpuNumber){
                System.out.println("You lose!\n"
                        + "Guess too low!");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("You lose!\n"
                            + "Guess too high!");
                }
        }

        if(playerNumber == cpuNumber){
            System.out.println("You have guessed correct. You win!");
        }
    }
```

}

What is more efficient from a good programming practice point of view?

Comment: You should not use static methods. Static methods makes larger applications harder to test, because you cannot change the object to a testing-only implementation.

Comment: So remove static methods, create a new instance of NumberGuess and change it like paulsm4 suggested. I will bare this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say neither looks better, IMHO. Also, Number is bad name for your own class, since there already is a class called java.lang.Number. Christian is right in that there's really no need for all those static methods. Yes, it takes the logic out of the main method so it doesn't look as "messy," but it doesn't solve your problem, and it usually results in spaghetti code. Furthermore, separating logic out into separate methods in that way can also cause you to write awkward code that allows those methods to pass information between one another (the reason you've created those static variables).

There's also hardly any point to creating an entire class that just encapsulates a single number and provides getters and setters, you could do this with a simple integer if you really wanted to. But I'd say the purpose of OOP is to organize related components into a container that's generic enough to be reused, not specific enough that it can't be used in other environments (i.e. GUI, console, net).

If I were writing it I might do something like:

```
import java.util.*;

class GuessingGame {
    private static final Random rng = new Random();
    private int number;

    public void generateNumber() {
        number = rng.nextInt(10);
    }

    public int guess(int guess) {
        return Integer.compare(guess, number);
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        GuessingGame game = new GuessingGame();
        game.generateNumber();
        System.out.println("Guess a number:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int result = game.guess(n);
        if (result < 0)
            System.out.println("You guessed too low!");
        else if (result > 0)
            System.out.println("You guessed too high!");
        else
            System.out.println("You win!");
        System.out.println("You guessed: " + n);
        System.out.println("The actual number was: " + game.getNumber());
    }
}
```

There's nothing wrong with having code in your main method, that's what it's there for. This is however a good instance where using a static variable would be useful, so that a new instance of Random isn't created every time you create a new number. This could also be expanded upon to include a minimum and maximum range that can be generated, and you might add a constructor to take just that.

Comment: It appears I need to work better on my code, I completely understand yours and it is a hella lot cleaner than mine. Practice makes perfect.I have never used the     Integer.compare method before

Comment: Just keep at it and you'll get there =). I just used [Integer.compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) because I noticed you print out if they guessed too low or high. The docs say that it returns "the value 0 if x == y; a value less than 0 if x < y; and a value greater than 0 if x > y." If all you wanted to do is check if they were equal then you could just make the guess method's return type a boolean and have it `return guess == number;`, either way is fine.

Comment: Yep, just read the Integer.compare documentation as you posted that, pretty neat method. My bad coding seems to come from "avoid crowding the main method" attitude I somehow developed.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Why not something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
...

public class NumberGuess {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       NumberGuess numberGuess = new NumberGuess ();
       int playerNumber = numberGuess.playerNumber();
       numberGuess.printResults();
       ...

   public int playerNumber () {
      ...

   public static int generateNumber() {
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I presume you are creating a new instance of NumberGuess so that you can access non static fields?